# trying to add the sum of two numbers from two different button clicks

Tags: java, android

imageview burger = 7.99 when clicked, imageview fries = 2.99 when clicked, I want to get the sum of both however when i click one after the other it refreshes and just adds the value inside instead of adding on to the previous value. I feel like the solution is right in front of me but i still have no idea what I am missing here.

```
public class ThirdActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static double price1 = 0;
static double price2 = 0;
TextView total;
double bill;
static int but1_value = 0;
static int but1_value1 = 0;
ImageView burger;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

    TextView tab = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Table_Size);

    burger = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.burger);

    total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price1);

    final ImageView fries = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fries);

    fries.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           

            price2 = price2 + 2.99;

            total.setText("Total: " + price2);
            

        }
    });


    burger.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            price1 = price1 + 7.99;

            total.setText("Total: " + price1);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to create global variable total_price.

```
private double total_price = 0;
```

Update the value of total_price whenever you click on fries

```
total_price += price1
```

and for burger

```
total_price += price2
```

and then set total as

```
total.setText("Total: " + total_price);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `total` you are either setting `price1` or `price2`.

You should set the addition of two, as your goal is.

```
total.setText("Total: " + (price1 + price2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned a new value to the variable `price1` from one place and to `price2` from another place.

If you want to maintain the value use a single variable and save in it from both places, or directly add them and set the value.

Use:

```
total.setText("Total: " + (price1+price2));
```